# Portable way to implement variadic arguments in kernel space?

Tags: c, assembly, variadic-functions, portability

I am wondering if it is possible to implement the variadic macros in C or assembly.

I would prefer to have at least va_start() be a C macro but looks like this might not be possible. I have seen other answers to different questions saying it is not possible to do in C because you have to rely on undefined behaviour.

For context I am writing a kernel and I do not want to rely on any specific C89 compiler or unix-like assembler. Building the source with any C compiler is important for the project. Keeping it simple is another goal, unfortunately supporting something like variadic arguments seems to be complex on some architectures (amd64 ABI).

I know the __builtin_va_start(v,l), __builtin_va_arg(v, l), etc. macros exist but these are only available to specific compilers?

Right now I have the kernel printf(, ...) and panic(, ...) routines written in assembly (i386 ABI) which setup the va_list (pointer to first va argument on the stack) and pass it to vprintf(, va_list) which then uses the va_arg() macro (written in C). This does not rely on any undefined or implementation defined behaviour but I would prefer that all the macros are written in C.

Comment: In pure C it would necessarily rely on what is UB at the level of the language.  You can do it in assembly, of course.  But I don't know what's wrong with just using your compiler's existing `va_start`; every conforming freestanding C implementation should provide it, and although its innards are implementation-dependent, all compilers supporting your chosen ABI will work correctly and interoperate.

Comment: There should be no reason to use `__builtin_va_start`, since plain `va_start` should expand to it or its equivalent; the `__builtin_` is basically just to match gcc's internal naming conventions.  It only creates gratuitous compiler dependence with no benefit.

Comment: @NateEldredge using va_start would be a problem because it is part of the external C library from the system you are building it on. The kernel source does not assume you have an externel C library.

Comment: Well, many compilers separate their internal code (needed to implement freestanding functionality) from the system library.  Stuff like `<stdarg.h>` is considered part of the compiler, not part of the system C library.  And in the case of gcc, any code needed for things like `va_start` would be in libgcc instead of libc.  If your compiler was configured properly, you are supposed to be able to link libgcc into a kernel or any other sort of bare-metal program; it doesn't need OS support.

Comment: In general you will need to be able to link libgcc anyway, since it may contain things needed for even more basic language features, like atomics or even division.

Comment: For instance, Linux used the compiler's `<stdarg.h>` until very recently, when for some reason (possibly licensing) they chose to copy-paste gcc's very short file into their own include file, instead of using the one installed on the host.  (They only support gcc anyway.)  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c0891ac15f0428ffa81b2e818d416bdf3cb74ab6

Comment: @NateEldredge I could use <stdarg.h> but it still lacks portability. I don't want to support a specific compiler implementation and I do not want the dependency of a C library when building the kernel source code. If there was a way to do it in the C standard that all compilers need to support I would use that. I understand the compilers have built in functions but the C standard says it should be in the C library and not in C as a type like 'int'. I want to eventually write a strictly compliant C compiler for the system (with maybe a few plan 9 C extensions) with no built-ins.

Comment: But `stdarg.h` **is** in the C standard!  It's part of what every *conforming freestanding implementation* is obliged to support; see C17 4p6.  And *freestanding* is just what you want for a kernel: it's the functionality of a compiler without the support of an OS or a "C library".  If your kernel will build with any conforming freestanding implementation, that's about as portable as you can get.

Comment: (And if you want to go back all the way to C89, the same holds: see [C89 section 1.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#1.7)).

Comment: @NateEldredge you answered most of my question but I am still confused about how the <stdarg.h> header works. Say you were building the source on a computer without any C libraries. If you had #include <stdarg.h> it would still compile?

Comment: @NateEldredge  At 2.1.2.1 Freestanding environment: There are otherwise no reserved external identifiers. Any library facilities available to a freestanding program are implementation-defined.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "without any C libraries", but for instance, gcc all by itself claims to be a conforming freestanding implementation.  Facilities like `<stdarg.h>` are therefore included as part of the gcc project; it does not rely on glibc or system C libraries to provide it.

Comment: "Freestanding environment" is not the same thing as "freestanding implementation".  Anyway, C17 clarifies that passage to say that "Any library facilities available to a freestanding program, **other than the minimal set
required by clause 4**, are implementation-defined."  Where `stdarg.h` is among the things mentioned in clause 4.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh ok cool, I think I am understanding the differences. A freestanding environment is more the kernel itself at run time. A freestanding implementation is more the compiler. So I can use <stdarg.h> to compile kernel source.

Comment: @NateEldredge I mean, say the system has no standard headers for the compiler to look for. But if I were to use <stdarg.h> in one of my kernel C source files the compiler will still compile the source code because <stdarg.h> more exists in the compiler and C language then it does as an actual header on the system?

Comment: It may exist as an actual file.  That's kind of beside the point as far as the C standard is concerned.  But for instance, on my Linux system, the file `stdarg.h` is found in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include/`, installed as part of the gcc package, instead of in `/usr/include` with the so-called system headers installed by the libc-dev package.  [...]

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that if `#include <stdarg.h>` doesn't work, then your compiler (as installed, with whatever options you are using) isn't a conforming freestanding implementation (CFI).  And it's a very modest requirement for your kernel to say "must be built with a compiler which is a CFI".  A kernel that builds with any CFI is as portable as anyone could reasonably expect.  If you try to replace `stdarg.h` with your own handwritten version, you will make your kernel *less* portable.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am using a cross compiler for i386. I don't mind saying that you need to build the system with any CFI but I just want to ensure that if you cross compile and do not have access to a C lib that you won't get an error and fail to compile. I just tested compiling <stdarg.h> and it used the header that the cross compiler provided. I think I was confused because a C library like musl libc provide the <stdarg.h> header and it is more something that the compiler should provide and not the C library implementation.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you, you completely cleared things up. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't know how this site works. Do you get points for answering stuff? If you want the points and write an answer I'll mark it answered.

Comment: Sure, I can try to write a complete answer at some point, but it may be a couple days before I get to it.

Comment: There's nothing portable in kernele space.  If you are talking about linux kernel, the thing will not be probably portable to windows kernel of FreeBSD kernel.  So please, think twice and edit your question to make subject clearer.

Comment: @LuisColorado My bad, I fixed it. When i said portability, what I really mean to say is being able to build the project with any tools.

Comment: @cbot, For many years, the build of linux kernel has been dependent on gcc and it is not possible to build it, even with CLANG.  I don't know what is the status now... but that's a huge task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Summary: **Just `#include <stdarg.h>` and use `va_start` and friends as you normally would.**  A standard-conformant C compiler will support this, even without what we normally think of as a "C library", and it is perfectly usable in a kernel that must run on the bare metal without OS support.  This is also the most portable solution, and avoids needing an architecture-, compiler- or ABI-dependent solution.

---

Of course when writing a kernel, you are used to not using library facilities like the functions from `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and even `<string.h>` (`printf, malloc, strcpy`, etc), or having to write your own. But `<stdarg.h>` is in a different category.  Its functionality can be provided by the compiler without OS support or extensive library code, and is in some sense more a part of the compiler/language than the "library".

From the point of view of the C standard, there are two kinds of *conforming implementations* (see C17 section 4, "Conformance").  Application programmers mostly think about *conforming hosted implementations*, which must provide `printf` and all that.  But for a kernel or embedded code or anything else that runs on the bare metal, what you want is a *conforming freestanding implementation* (I'll write CFI for short).  This is, informally speaking, "just the compiler" without "the standard library".  But there are a few standard headers whose contents a CFI must still support, and `<stdarg.h>` is one of them.  The others are things like `<limits.h>`, `<stddef.h>`  and `<stdint.h>` that are mainly constants, macros and typedefs.

(This same distinction has existed all the way back to C89, with the same guarantee of `<stdarg.h>` being available.)

If your kernel will build with any CFI, that's pretty much the gold standard of portability for a kernel.  In fact, you'll be pretty hard-pressed not to use some more compiler-specific feature at some points (inline assembly is awfully useful, for instance).  But `<stdarg.h>` doesn't have to be one of them; you're really not giving up any portability by using it.  You can expect it to be supported by any usable compiler targeting any given architecture, and that includes cross compilers (which will be configured to use the correct header for the target).  For instance, in the case of a GNU system, `<stdarg.h>` ships with the gcc compiler itself, and not with the glibc standard library.

As some further assurance, until very recently, the Linux kernel itself used `<stdarg.h>` in precisely this way.  (About a month ago there was a [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/c0891ac15f0428ffa81b2e818d416bdf3cb74ab6) to create their own `<linux/stdarg.h>` file, which just copy-pastes from an old version of gcc's `<stdarg.h>` and defines the macros as their gcc-specific `__builtin` versions.  Linux only supports building with gcc anyway, so this doesn't hurt them.  But my best guess is that this was done for licensing reasons - the commit message emphasizes that they copied a GPL 2 version - rather than based on anything technical.)

---

By contrast, writing your variadic functions in assembly will naturally tie you to that specific architecture, and they'd be one more thing to be rewritten if you ever want to port to another architecture.  And trying to access variadic arguments on the stack from C, with tricks like `arg = *((int *)&fixed_arg + 1)`, is (a) ABI-dependent, (b) only possible at all for ABIs which actually pass args on the stack, which these days isn't much besides x86-32, and (c) is undefined behavior that might be "miscompiled" by some compilers.  Finally, things like `__builtin_va_start` are strictly compiler-dependent (gcc and clang in this case), and using `<stdarg.h>` is no worse  because gcc's `<stdarg.h>` simply contains macros like `#define va_start __builtin_va_start`.

Comment: Fun fact: The Linux kernel on x86-32 is built with `-mregparm=3`, so it's using a register-arg calling convention even there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are highlighting *kernel space*, is it right that you want a *user space* function which is implemented via some sort of *kernel call* and is variadic?
This is a bit problematic; as a typical kernel entry point transitions the flow of control onto a *kernel stack*.  Your *va_start(), va_arg()* implementations would have to be aware of how to traverse to the user's stack, and possibly map bits of a register save area into the vector.

An easier approach would be to have the user function:

```
int ufunc(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list v;
    int n;
    va_start(v, fmt);
    n = __ufunc(fmt, v);
    va_end(v);
    return n;
}
```

And implement *__ufunc* in the kernel.   Traditionally this is how the *execl* and *execv* family of functions co-operate to make handy interfaces, but only use one kernel call.

Your kernel will still have a bit of work dealing with the user stack though.  For example, I could craft a va_list value for your call that caused the kernel to read out some private data.  But if you are able to sort that the va_list points somewhere valid, and whatever processing you are doing with *va_arg()* supplied values are also valid, you would be able to use the stock compiler provided implementation.

Do note that if the user program used a different calling convention than your kernel, you could be in for a bit of work.   For example, microsoft ignored the published ABI for the amd64, so that might cause a problem.

Comment: No I was wondering if I could get around the implementation and undefined behaviour of having variadic arguments in the kernel functions such as the panic(, ...). apparently if I get the address of the parameter on the stack it might not actually be the address of the parameter on the stack and the compiler could have moved it somewhere else by the time you reference it.